# Complementi di luogo e preposizioni

Tags: prepositions

Di solito i complementi di luogo richiedono la preposizione "in" ma se si tratta di un luogo abituale (da non essere considerato luogo fisico) si usa "a".
Ecco degli esempi:
Vado al bar, ma Vado IN un bar, IN che bar vai? Bar in cui vai.

Ci sono però casi in cui si usa "a" in tutti i contesti... con parole come "festa":
Vado alla festa, ad una festa, festa a cui vado, a quale festa vai?

Lo stesso dovrebbe accadere con parole come "cassa, fermata, tavolo, piano, specchio, ingresso ecc..."
Esempi:
Abito/scendo al primo piano/ad un piano, a che piano abiti/scendi? Il piano a cui abito/scendo.
Lavoro ad una cassa/alla cassa 4/la cassa a cui lavori. 
Mi guardo allo specchio/ad uno speccho, specchio al quale mi guardo, a quale specchio ti guardi?

La mia analisi è corretta o forse sbaglio qualcosa?

Comment: Benvenuto/a su ItalianSE!

Comment: Non ho capito bene la tua domanda, e in effetti ci sono vari possibili dubbi sull'uso di “a” e “in”, ma in alcuni dei tuoi esempi l'alternativa sarebbe improponibile. Per esempio, nessuno lavora _in_ una cassa, se è vivo. Una festa o un piano non sono luoghi chiusi _in_ cui si possa stare. Invece _in_ uno specchio si può benissimo guardare (“Ora vediamo come in uno specchio”). Infine, che cosa intendi per “gresso”?

Comment: Intendevo ingresso.

Comment: Con parole come cassa (del supermecato ad esempio) ingresso, piano ecc... si usa la preposozione "a"..                                                       volevo sapere se ciò che ho scritto era corretto o meno.

Comment: Non volevo sapere se con parole per esempio come ingresso oppure tavolo si usa in... perché so che non si usa. Volevo sapere se tutte le frasi dell'ultimo paragrafo (a partire da "abito/scendo") sono corrette

Comment: Capisco che le preposizioni siano l’argomento forse più difficile per chi impara l’italiano. Purtroppo, non ci sono regole generali. Quindi, in realtà non è vero che i complementi di luogo di solito richiedono “in”. Per quanto riguarda i tuoi esempi, non capisco il significato di «abito a un piano», «lavoro a una cassa» e «la cassa a cui lavori». Poi, come ha già fatto notare DaG, sii dice «Mi guardo in uno specchio».

Comment: Io dico "abito al primo piano" ... ma se volessi usare l'articolo indeterminativo per specificare che è un piano qualsiasi? Lo stesso per quanto riguardo "cassa" ... per esempio, immaginando una discussione :" a che piano abiti?" abito ad un piano compreso tra il primo e il terzo!" ma non faresti meglio a indicarmi il piano a cui abiti? "                Ecco lo stesso discorso(o quantomeno simile)  lo farei con altre parole come "cassa, ingresso" ecc... sbaglio?

Comment: I tuoi esempi con la cassa e il piano, una volta chiarito il possibile contesto, vanno bene.